# HTTP Request not Working with Retrofit but it's work fine in Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2, postman, okhttp

I am facing a weird problem .. I am in middle of developing application and all my requests works fine but the last three didn't work with no reason !! 
I searched for what could cause this problem but i didn't understand anything ... although the request just works fine in Postman !!

here is my request function :

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("addContractBenefit")
    Call<ResponseBody> addContractBenefit(   @Header("Accept") String Accept,
                                             @Header("Authorization") String token,
                                             @Field ("contract_id") int contract_id ,
                                             @Field ("contract_benefit") String contract_benefit
    );
```

and here is my requset call :

```
 Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addContractBenefit("application/json","Bearer "+prefManager.getAPIToken() , contract_id , b.contractBenefit.getText().toString() );
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                String jsonStr = null;
                try {
                    jsonStr = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("response" , jsonStr);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject statesResponses = json.optJSONObject("states");
                    boolean success = statesResponses.getBoolean("success");
                    if(success){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.added_successefuly), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        benefitAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        b.contractBenefits.invalidateViews();
                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("failure", t.getMessage());
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }});
```

and RetrofitClientInstance

```
  public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

all of my other requests is working fine but i don't know what causing error in these request !!

Comment: What error you are facing ?

Comment: response is null , and it doesn't store on seever

Comment: for me it was filesize issue please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55913121/3904109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was server error it takes another Character set/Collection which is make it not work with retrofit but work on postman

Comment: Can you elaborate?